# Orthogonal Property of Legendre Polynomials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, orthogonality, legendre-polynomials

How can I get $$nu_{n} + (n-1)u_{n-1},$$ where 
$$u_{n} = \int_{-1}^{1} x^{-1}P_{n-1}(x) P_{n}(x)\, \mathrm {d}x\; ? $$

I did many search, and also I did try by myself. But without a success. 
Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the Legendre-polynomials. I am taking information about them from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):

First, I use [Bonnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Definition_via_generating_function)'s recursion formula
$$
(n+1) P_{n+1}(x) = (2n + 1) x P_n(x) - n P_{n-1}(x)
$$
and rewrite it for $n-1$ instead of $n$ (because I want to get rid of $P_{n-2}$ in the expression you want to calculate):
$$
n P_{n}(x) = (2n -1) x P_{n-1}(x) - (n-1) P_{n-2}(x)
$$
We solve for $P_{n-2}$.
$$
P_{n-2}(x)=\frac{(2n -1) x P_{n-1}(x)-nP_{n}(x)}{(n-1)}
$$

Now the expression can be calculated.
\begin{align*}
n u_n+(n-1)u_{n-1} &= \int_{-1}^1 n x^{-1} P_{n-1}(x) P_{n}(x) + (n-1) x^{-1} P_{n-2}(x) P_{n-1}(x) dx \\
&=\int_{-1}^1 n x^{-1} P_{n-1}(x) P_{n}(x) +  x^{-1} \bigg( (2n -1) x P_{n-1}(x)-nP_{n}(x)\bigg)P_{n-1}(x) dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 n x^{-1} P_{n-1}(x) P_{n}(x) - n x^{-1} P_{n-1}(x) P_{n}(x)  +(2n -1) P_{n-1}^2(x) dx \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 (2n -1) P_{n-1}^2(x) dx
\end{align*}
Now we use the [orthonormalization formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthonormality_and_completeness)
$$
\int_{-1}^1 P_i(x) P_j(x) dx = \frac{2}{2i+1} \delta_{ij}
$$
for $i=j=n-1$ to get the final result
$$
n u_n+(n-1)u_{n-1} = (2n-1)\frac{2}{2(n-1)+1} = 2
$$